# How do you apply for a refresh token in the LinkedIn API?

Tags: linkedin-api

We have a client application that runs on Windows that is used by thousands of users in the financial market in order to make analyses and charts. Since long we have an integration with Twitter where you can easily post a chart together with short text. Many users have asked us to implement a similar feature for LinkedIn since this is becoming increasingly popular among our users.

The API for sharing on LinkedIn works fine for us, but we need to refresh the access token every 60th day, which cannot be made completely seamless for the user. Since our application is not a web app, we need to launch a browser on order to refresh the access token and this is disruptive for the users.

The docs at [Authorization Code Flow (3-legged OAuth)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context) says that some selected partners can get refresh tokens as a complement to access tokens. That would be perfect for our integration. How can we become one of those "partners"? I have not found any information how to apply for this.

I have looked for a way to apply to become a partner that can get a refresh token, but failed to find any information.

Comment: [Partner Programs](https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs)?

Comment: Possibly, but this is not related to any of the partner programs Talent, Marketing or Sales. We are just interested in making LinkedIn Share a smooth experience for our users.

Comment: "Applications are only accepted when we feel that they're providing value to members, developers and LinkedIn." So if you want to become a partner you need to also provide value for members and LinkedIn. It doesn't allow you to just partner up because it suits your(or your users') needs.

Comment: Yes, sure. The purpose here is for our users. We have a shared interest in having happy users so this is good for us and it is good for LinkedIn. The that thing is that we are not interested in pulling data from the LinkedIn DB, so none of the partner programs I have found fits the bill. I thought that perhaps some at MS/LinkedIn could chip in (or contact me directly) or perhaps that someone else have any idea how to reach the right persons.